# Ordering Column Names in R

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have done ordered column names

```
MAIN_CARD <- lapply(MAIN_CARD,function(x) x <- x %>% select(order(colnames(x))))
head(MAIN_CARD[[1]])
```

[image]

but I want to have BAD_PERFORMANCE_1 BAD_PERFORMANCE_2 BAD_PERFORMANCE_3 until BAD_PERFORMANCE_12 in order

Thank you for helping

Comment: Could you please include reproducible data? Is MAIN_CARD a data frame, or a list of data frames? It's not especially clear from your code.

Comment: No need to sort, just remake the names: `myData <- mydata[, paste0("BAD_PERFORMANCE_", 1:12)]`

Comment: I have edited my question... its list of dataframe